# Round off the results to two decimal places

Tags: javascript, decimal

I'm working on my javascript. I want it to sum in two decimal places. So if I add:
25.321+300.693 = 326.014

I want the sum to be: 326.01. Here's my code:

```
function civ(){
civ1=Number(document.addition.scc.value);
civ2=Number(document.addition.ccc.value);
civ3=Number(document.addition.ncc.value);
civ4=Number(document.addition.vch.value);
civ5=Number(document.addition.mch.value);
civ6=Number(document.addition.nlch.value);
civ7=Number(document.addition.slch.value);
valNum1=civ1+civ2+civ3+civ4+civ5+civ6+civ7;
document.addition.civ123.value=valNum1;
}
```

I also try this one:

```
function civ(){
civ1=Number(document.addition.scc.value);
civ2=Number(document.addition.ccc.value);
civ3=Number(document.addition.ncc.value);
civ4=Number(document.addition.vch.value);
civ5=Number(document.addition.mch.value);
civ6=Number(document.addition.nlch.value);
civ7=Number(document.addition.slch.value);
valNum1=Math.round(civ1+civ2+civ3+civ4+civ5+civ6+civ7*100)/100;
document.addition.civ123.value=valNum1;
}
```

But the result is incorrect. I add 2 numbers again (128.65 + 0 ) = 1.29 or 1.28 (I forgot). Thanks for those who will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

order of operations...

```
Math.round((civ1+civ2+civ3+civ4+civ5+civ6+civ7)*100)/100;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var num = 15.65686354785
var newnum = (num.toString().length > 4 ? num.toFixed(2) : num);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this 
valNum1=Math.round((civ1+civ2+civ3+civ4+civ5+civ6+civ7)*100)/100;
you misplace the braces